# How to receive email GMAIL with LARAVEL?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, gmail, gmail-api

I want to receive my mail (INBOX GMAIL) in my laravel application (5.x). 
But I don't know how to do this. 
I think I need to use a listener : when a mail arrives in my INBOX, I want a  laravel event to read the email and save automatically the fields in my database (Subject, Message, Attachments...).
 Then the mail in my INBOX will be in status "read".

Can you help me ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Go through [this package](https://packagist.org/packages/dacastro4/laravel-gmail) may be you are looking for this.

Comment: Hum, it's almost that. In fact, I want display the mail inbox in my application for all users. And I don't login at GMAIL to obtain my email. The login is transparent for the user. It's laravel who connect at my GMAIL. 

The application is a ticketing system :). You see the problem?

Comment: You can do that with that package. It's not going to be an out-of-the-box solution, though - you're going to have to write substantial code here.

Comment: Ok thanks I try to program with this in the first time ;). Thanks you :) !

Answer (score 0):

Interesting way to look at this but why not just have it send messages to the ticketing system and completely manage it there?

You would need to take a look at https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/

Basically you would just be managing emails in a different application. There are also rate limits to be aware of depending on the scope of this system.

It would be safer in that event to have gmail forward the emails to the ticketing system and 100% manage it there and use SMTP to just reply from the system.

Comment: Thanks you for your response. The specifications of the application say that the mail must be downloaded from GMAIL and store in the application.
Each email stored in the database have a processus with more status and different user well defined.
So if I check GMAIL API, I must be able to store this in the application right ?